# Multi sort in GSA

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is that even possible?

Foe example, I have the following records,

```
<MT N="ORDER_number" V="123"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="abc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="011"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="bbc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="011"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="abc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="121"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="abc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="022"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="bbc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="125"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="bbc"/>
```

and the desired sort order is below,

```
<MT N="ORDER_number" V="011"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="abc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="121"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="abc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="123"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="abc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="011"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="bbc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="121"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="bbc"/>

<MT N="ORDER_number" V="125"/>
<MT N="Document_TypeE" V="bbc"/>
```

**sort=meta:order_number.meta:documenttypeE** <-- Is this even possible? to do multi-level sorting like this? Documentation does not say a way to do this. So I'm assuming this is not possible in GSA. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry,

Multi-dimensional search is not available on the GSA